# Need a batch file to start, delay a close, and restart another batch file.

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have searched and searched and this is the closest code I have found:

```
@echo off
:loop
C:\CryptoCurrency\nexus_cpuminer\start.bat
timeout /t 30 >null
taskkill /f /im nexus_cpuminer.exe >nul
goto loop
```

A few things: notice the start.bat. The .exe I need to launch has to start via the .bat file because the .bat file contains information the .exe needs.

Secondly, the .exe launches a CMD prompt window which shows me what's going on.
(keep this in mind because this is not your normal .exe, I WANT that CMD prompt window to close when it's KILLED)

I am aware I have it set for 30 seconds. I'm just testing right now. I'd like to set it for 4 hours before the kill command is called. Also, I'd like to set a "delay" of 30 seconds before the whole process starts over. I am running Windows 7 x 64.

Comment: And what's the question? What exactly does your code not do that you want it to do (or vice versa)?

Comment: Note that: **1.** You never should give a .bat file the same name of a command. `start` is an internal cmd.exe command. **2.** The line that ends in `start.bat` imply to **transfer** the control to such a file _and never return_! If you want to return to this .bat file after that .bat file ends, you must use `call ..\start.bat` command. **However** I don't know what would happen in this case where `start` is the name of an internal command (first change the name of such a file).

Comment: **3.** You have a deadlock: the control will return to this .bat file _until the `start.bat` file ends_; this means that there is no way to execute the `taskkill` command at same time that `nexus_cpuminer.exe` is running. To solve this problem, you must use the internal `start` command in order to start the second .bat file in parallel and then continue with the rest of this .bat file.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the name of the second Batch file to other name (i.e. `starter.bat`) and execute it via the `start` internal command in order to execute it in parallel:

```
@echo off
:loop
start "" cmd /C "C:\CryptoCurrency\nexus_cpuminer\starter.bat"
timeout /t 30 >null
taskkill /f /im nexus_cpuminer.exe >nul
goto loop
```

The last line in `starter.bat` file must be the execution of `nexus_cpuminer.exe`, so when it is killed via `taskkill`, the .bat file ends immediately.

Another simpler approach is to directly execute `nexus_cpuminer.exe` in *this* Batch file, via `start "" cmd /C nexus_cpuminer.exe` command, so this process be opened in its own cmd.exe window.

Answer (score 0):

If you **CALL** **start.bat**, it will return to your 'calling' script.
If you give **start.bat** a **TITLE**, you can **/FI**lter your **TASKKILL** command to **EQ** that **WINDOWTITLE**